# Redirect a system call output to a file with Java

Tags: java, multithreading, logging, file-io, iostream

Currently having troubles to redirect the output of a small windows batch console to a log file. My Java application needs to start the Runtime.exec() call without waiting it to finish and still log the output. Here is my logger class :

```
public class BatchThreadLogger extends Thread {
  private Process process;
  private String logFilePath;
  private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(BatchThreadLogger.class);

  public BatchThreadLogger(Process process, String logFilePath) {
    this.process = process;
    this.logFilePath = logFilePath;
  }

  public void run() {
    try {
      // create logging file
      File file = new File(logFilePath);
      file.createNewFile();

      // create a writer object
      OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(file);
      PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(os);

      // catch the process output in an InputStream
      InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream());
      BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);

      // wait for the process to complete
      int processStatus = process.waitFor();

      // redirect the output to the log file
      String line = null;
      while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        pw.println(line);
      }

      // add a small message with the return code to the log
      pw.println("********************************************");
      pw.println("********************************************");
      pw.println("Batch call completed with return status " + processStatus);

      pw.flush();
      os.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
      logger.error("IOException raised during batch logging on file " + logFilePath, e);
    }
    catch (InterruptedException e) {
      logger.error("InterruptedException raised during batch process execution", e);
    }
  }
}
```

My call is quite simple :

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
BatchThreadLogger logger = new BatchThreadLogger(process, logFilePath);
logger.start();
```

My command is currently just calling my test.bat with two parameters. My test batch now just do :

```
echo "BATCH CALLED WITH PARAMETER %1 AND %2"
exit
```

My log file however does contains only :

```
********************************************
********************************************
Batch call completed with return status 0
```

I tried to place the `waitFor()`call before and after the code redirecting the output to the log file, without success. I always see the black screen of the command being launched, but nothing in logs...

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I'm missing something, but cannot understand what...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not reading from the standard error of the process you create.

I suspect that an error message is being written to the standard error, and because you're only reading from standard output, you're not picking up this error.

I would recommend replacing your use of `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(...)` with a [ProcessBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html), using something like the following:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe", "/c", "test.bat", "One", "Two");
pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
Process process = pb.start();
```

The line `pb.redirectErrorStream(true);` redirects the process' standard error into its standard output, so that you don't have to read from two streams (standard output and standard error) in two separate threads.

Comment: I'm not sure about your answer. I wonder how echo-ing a text in a batch file can be considered as an error and thus directed to the error stream of the process execution. Just to be sure, I replaced the `getInputStream()` call by a `getErrorStream()` and it still does not work... nothing in the log file...

Comment: I also added a random `ping www.google.ch` after the echo call, just to be sure that echo output does not redirect to a special stream or any trick like this... still nothing in logs. BTW, the code I posted does work on Linux. Regarding your ProcessBuilder proposition, I'll see if it can replace the `Runtime.exec()` call easilly.

Comment: I imagine you can get an error attempting to run a batch file that doesn't exist or can't be read due to permissions issues.  Still, it's odd that there's no output.  Would you mind sharing exactly what is in your `command` variable?  Also what sort of application (e.g. command-line, web-app, GUI, service) is this part of?

Comment: Sure, the command is `cmd /c start C:/ieu/test.bat spjc010j SPJ5000006000010101010`. This is started from a Web application running under JBoss 7 in a SessionBean.

Comment: Is there a reason why you're using `start`?  Have you tried running your command without `start`?  `start` runs a program in a separate command-prompt window, and the output from the program you run using `start` goes to this new window, not to your `process`.

Comment: I think you get the point. It seems to work without the `start` option. But better, it seems also to work without the `cmd /c`. I placed this part because that was the exact command I would launch in the windows command line. However, the `Runtime.exec()` does NOT act like a link to the command line, but rather as a program launcher. The real program I want to launch is indeed the `test.bat` and not the `cmd.exe`. Thanks for your help. I will still try your ProcessBuilder proposal and see if it is better than the current solution.